# UNIX - testing for file across ssh and returning True on original host

Tags: unix, ssh

Need to check for distribution of a file in an array programmatically. Logging into a master server and then would like to check for file on workers using simple ssh. So far I have:

```
ssh $HOSTNAME "[ -e '$HOSTNAME:/directory/filename' ] && echo 'Exists'"
```

Based on some of the logging output, I know the ssh is successful, but how can I get the test to return a message to the master server? Running the above returns nothing.

Comment: since the command is executed on the remote server, you have to `-e '/directory/filename'` instead of `-e '$HOSTNAME:/directory/filename'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSH will exit with the same exit code as the command that you run on the remote host. If that command is a test, then the exit code will match what you would normally expect from a test.

I would suggest the following:

- Simplify your command to only run the test over SSH
- Run the echo on your local machine
- It doesn't seem correct that you have `$HOSTNAME:` in front of your path.

```
ssh "$HOSTNAME" "test -e '/directory/filename'" && echo 'Exists'
```

I personally find `if` statements to be much more easily understandable, which is an optional change if you are willing to go that route:

```
if ssh "$HOSTNAME" "test -e '/directory/filename'"; then
    echo "Exists"
else
    echo "Does not exist" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```